# Default export in ES6. Why don't you need a semicolon?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm reading this from the [exploringjs about ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)

> #### 17.1.2 Single default export
>
> There can be a single default export. For example, a function:
>
> ```
> //------ myFunc.js ------   
> export default function () { ··· } // no semicolon!
>
> //------ main1.js ------  
> import myFunc from 'myFunc';
> myFunc();
> ```
>
> Or a class:
>
> ```
> //------ MyClass.js ------  
> export default class { ··· } // no semicolon!
>
> //------ main2.js ------  
> import MyClass from 'MyClass';
> let inst = new MyClass();
> ```
>
> Note that there is no semicolon at the end if you
> default-export a function or a class (which are anonymous
> declarations).

Why do you not use a semi-colon at the end of the export default declaration? I thought you end all statements with semi-colons?

Answer (score 16):

> Why don't you need a semicolon?

Because the [grammar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-imports) doesn't define a semicolon there:

```
export default HoistableDeclaration
export default ClassDeclaration
export default [lookahead ∉ {function, class}] AssignmentExpression ;
```

(unless you have an expression)

> I thought you end all statements with semi-colons?

That's not true at all. Have you ever put a semicolon after a block? If someone writes

```
if (...) {

};
```

then it is by mistake.

It may seem that all statements are terminated by semicolons, because at the end / bottom of most statements, you end up having an [*ExpressionStatement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-expression-statement) or empty statement, which both are terminated by semicolons.

Besides that, an *ExportDeclaration* is not a statement.

Comment: Is a block considered a statement?

Comment: Yes: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations. Otherwise you would not be able to use it in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 5):

> I thought you end all statements with semi-colons?

Yes, but declarations are no statements. This is not specific for exports, you don't put semicolons after normal function declarations either.

Btw, in statements you don't actually *need* semicolons, as JavaScript has [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572) - it only is good practise.

Answer (score 2):

The [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion) specifies:

> Most ECMAScript statements and declarations must be terminated with a
>   semicolon. Such semicolons may always appear explicitly in the source
>   text. For convenience, however, such semicolons may be omitted from
>   the source text in certain situations. These situations are described
>   by saying that semicolons are automatically inserted into the source
>   code token stream in those situations.

**So, IMO, if in an ES6 environment, and (especially) if you are working on server-side JavaScript, feel free to omit semi-colons in situations where it is obvious there will be no ill-effect.**

Also see [this article](http://webapplog.com/seven-things-you-should-stop-doing-with-node-js/).

[This](https://github.com/npm/npm-expansions/blob/master/build.js) is a good example of withholding semi-colons.