# Semicolon after default export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482309/default-export-in-es6-why-dont-you-need-a-semicolon) that I don't need to put a semicolon after default exports. So this program has an unnecessary semicolon:

```
export default function() {};
```

But if my module continues like this:

```
export default function() {};

(() => {
  // creating a new function scope
})();
```

then I can't leave the semicolon.

So what is going on here? The grammar says I don't need the semicolon but if I leave it the code means something else?

**UPDATE:**

If I leave the semicolon:

```
export default function() {}

(() => {
  // creating a new function scope
})();
```

then the exported function gets called instead of being exported. [babeljs.io](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=export%20default%20function()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20creating%20a%20new%20function%20scope%0D%0A%7D)()%3B) compiles the latter into:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports["default"] = (function () {})(function () {
  // creating a new function scope
})();

;
module.exports = exports["default"];
```

More precisely after it gets called an error is thrown, because the return value of the first function also gets called (but that is not a function). The error I get in chrome is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function(…)
```

Comment: What makes you not able to leave the semicolon in the second case? Does something give you an error?

Comment: @loganfsmyth please see my update

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default export in ES6. Why don't you need a semicolon?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33482309/1048572) (if your question wasn't about the babel bug)

Comment: @Bergi `I read here that I don't need to put a semicolon...` I forgot to link the question :( the question you linked inspired my own. At first I suspected inconsistency in the spec itself, then it turned out it is probably a babel bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to add a semicolon after a `export default` when it's followed by a function declaration, that's what the [grammar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports) says.

Babel is wrong, I've [filed a bug](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6768?workflow=create) against it. That code should be interpreted as exporting the function and then running the IIFE as an IIFE.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is true. in this case, it's still a function declaration, rather than a function expression, so it shouldn't require a semicolon after it. Generally for export syntax, the question of semicolons comes down to whether it would have had a semicolon if you left the `export` part out of the statement.

Comment: Hmm http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports (it's HoistableDeclaration if you were not aware).

Comment: @loganfsmyth it's a function declaration that requires semicolons to prevent automatic semicolon insertion. Indeed there was no case of this in ES5 and indeed the semicolon is not a part of the statement and is not really automatically inserted - interesting case indeed. I wonder if the grammar should be amended. I'll raise it in esdiscuss.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm starting to think this is a babel bug.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Some versions of WebStorm even raised a warning if I did put a semicolon, telling me I don't even need that. The current one I use (10.0.4) doesn't have that warning

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So based on the spec, I shouldn't be able to `export default "a string literal"`, as only HoistableDeclaration, ClassDeclaration and AssignmentExpression is allowed? I used `export default {...} // an object literal` everywhere

Comment: It's fine to `export default` an object literal - it's parsed as an `AssigmentExpression` and not a `HoistableDeclaration`.

Comment: Yeah you were right, I managed to trace it down: `AssignmentExpression, BitwiseANDExpression, EqualityExpression, RelationalExpression, ShiftExpression, AdditiveExpression, MultiplicativeExpression, UnaryExpression, PostfixExpression, LeftHandSideExpression, NewExpression, MemberExpression, PrimaryExpression, ObjectLiteral`